# Finding a value of a list

Tags: groovy

I have two lists

```
def flagList = SystemFlag.list()
```

this contains the domain objects of one table

I have another list which I create using a query. One of the parameter in the object of this list is contained in the flagList. How can I find if an id of FlagList is present in the second list?

I can do it in plain java but I need to use Groovy for this.

Comment: Can you rephrase this into a question? Example lists and what output you want would be a great help to understanding...

Comment: +1 to @tim_yates. It sounds that you may be able to make it work with a [`find`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method call. But as it also sounds that you are using Grails and its domain objects, that probably wouldn't be a good answer as Grails provides ways to test is an object with a given property exists on the database without having to retrieve all the instances of that class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found it using

```
def it = itemtofindsomehow
list.findIndexof  { iterator ->
  iterator.domain.id == it.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you have this situation:

```
def listeOne = [1,2,3,4,5]

def listTwo = [2,5,1]
```

You want to see if '2' of 'listTwo' is in 'listOne'.

Find a specific value:

```
def found = 2 in listTwo //returns a boolean of the interger 2 is in listTwo
```

Search for common value of both lists:

```
def intersectionsList = listOne.intersect(listTwo) //gives you a list of value that are in BORTH list
```

You can also iterate like this:

```
listTwo.each { value -> 
 if(value in listOne) println value //or do something lese
}
```

Alternatively:

```
listTwo.each { value ->
 listOne.find {value}?.toString() //you can perform an action on the object found in listOne. using '?.' will make sure no nullpointer will be thrown if there is no result. 
}
```